# hgsvn pushed file differs from local. How this can happen?

Tags: svn, mercurial, hgsvn

I have a fairly large (89M) binary file which I committed to an svn repo from a mercurial checkout. The file as committed to the repository differs from the file in the checkout, as evidenced by checking it out separately and computing the md5sum. However, my mercurial checkout reports the file as clean. I've pulled in new revisions from the svn repo, but the file remains different but clean. It's like the push to the svn repo was corrupted and hg is unable to tell. What could possibly cause this?

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably caused by newline conversion - if your setting specify native newlines and you are running windows then all `0x0a 0x0d` sequences will have been converted to `0x0d` on upload and will be converted back on download to a windows machine but not to a Unix machine..